# Dataset load issue with Person Accounts and Business Accounts

Tags: cumulusci

I generated mapping and extracted dataset based on the mapping, but now when I am trying to load it, it keeps failing on Person Account fields. I suspect it is because both the Person Accounts and Business Accounts are in the same table and you can't load Business Accounts with Person Account fields.

The only solution we could think of is splitting the mapping into 2 files, where one mapping would be for Person Accounts and the other for Business Accounts.

Is this what you are supposed to do, or are we doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. Saying things like "it keeps failing" without providing any details isn't useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this using the `soql_filter` key on two different steps, both pointed at the Account object.  If they need to have different fields, you can specify a different table name.

I don't have an environment to test this, but I believe this should work:

```
Insert Accounts:
  sf_object: Account
  table: Account
  fields:
    - Name
  soql_filter = 'IsPersonAccount = FALSE'

Insert PersonAccounts:
  sf_object: Account
  table: PersonAccount
  fields:
    - Name
    - IsPersonAccount
  soql_filter = 'IsPersonAccount = TRUE'
```

More information on the `soql_filter` key as well as the `sql_filter` key that works in the opposite direction is available in the CumulusCI docs:
https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/data.html#advanced-features

Comment: The problem with this is, that it will try to create 2 RecordType mapping tables with the same name for each Account table. Which is a big no no.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have a ton of experience in the record type tables as they were added long after I was hacking at that code in prototype phase.  You appear to be correct that the sf_object is used to generate the table name.  It seems like the table should be used instead per your use case: https://github.com/SFDO-Tooling/CumulusCI/blob/main/cumulusci/tasks/bulkdata/mapping_parser.py#L128-L134

Comment: But how do I make it use table instead of sf_object to generate two distinct recordtype tables? I am just running cci run task generate_dataset_mapping, cci run task extract_dataset and cci run task load_dataset.

Comment: I think that would require a change to CumulusCI's source code.  I'd recommend either opening an enhancement request in the GitHub repo (https://github.com/SFDO-Tooling/CumulusCI) or asking in the CumulusCI group in the Trailblazer community which is more actively monitored by the CumulusCI team.  I can't say for sure what complications would come from switching it to use table name rather than sf_object name but it sounds reasonable on the surface at least.

Comment: alright, thank you :)